# Get id From imageView and Set image as Wallpaper Onclick

Tags: android, button, imageview

I have an Imageview and a Button in my project, i want the button to set the image as homescreen background but i am getting error "imageView" cannot be resolved in the line "Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();"

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

 public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
    }


 public void setaswall(View view) { // SET AS WALLPAPER BUTTON
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
      = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
     try {
      Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
      if(bitmap!=null)
      myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
 };
 public void setaswall(View view) { // SET AS WALLPAPER BUTTON
     WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager 
     = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
     };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your imageView as global, so you have it in scope when you use it on setaswall(View view), instead of creating it only in onCreate()

Like this:

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

private ImageView _imageView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

And then, on setaswall(View view):

```
    Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)_imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        if(bitmap!=null)
            myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
```